# Tkinter matplotlib figure update instead of creating new one

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter

So I am creating a very basic GUI for some data. I want some of this data to be plotted directly in the GUI and I am using matplotlib + tkinter for this purpose. I have managed to obtain the plot, but I want to be able to select new data and then refresh the plot. Instead, now the program creates a new plot underneath the first one, instead of clearing the first and creating a new one. Could someone help me?

My code is as follows:

```
class App(tk.Frame):
    class App(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        super().__init__(master)
        self.master = master
        self.master.title("Classification of fUS data")
        self.master.geometry('1500x900')
        self.numdata = 0
        self.filepath = ""
        self.variable_regions = []
        
        self.data_frame = tk.Frame(self.master, borderwidth=2, relief='groove', background='red',height=250, width=250)
        self.data_frame.place(x = 0, y = 0)
        
        self.regions_frame = tk.Frame(self.master, borderwidth=2, relief='groove', background='blue',height=500, width=250)
        self.regions_frame.place(x = 0, y = 170)
        
        self.list_regions_frame = tk.Frame(self.master, borderwidth=2, relief='groove', background='white',height=400, width=200)
        self.list_regions_frame.place(x = 25, y = 215)
        
        self.plot_frame = tk.Frame(self.master, borderwidth=2, relief='groove', background='green',height=650, width=650)
        self.plot_frame.place(x = 400, y = 40)
        
        self.load_title = tk.Label(self.data_frame, text="Load New Data")
        self.load_title.place(x=0, y=0)
        

        self.data_name_label = tk.Button(self.data_frame, text="No data", width=30, border=0)
        self.data_name_label.place(x = 0, y = 40)
        self.data_name_label.bind("<Button-1>", self.load_data)
        
        self.data_name_label1 = tk.Button(self.data_frame, text="No data", width=30, border=0)
        self.data_name_label1.place(x = 0, y = 80)
        self.data_name_label1.bind("<Button-1>", self.load_data)
        
        self.data_name_label2 = tk.Button(self.data_frame, text="No data", width=30, border=0)
        self.data_name_label2.place(x = 0, y = 120)
        self.data_name_label2.bind("<Button-1>", self.load_data)
        
        
        self.regions_data = tk.Button(self.regions_frame, text="Load Regions:", width=30, border=0, command = self.load_regions)
        self.regions_data.place(x=0, y = 0)
        self.regions_data = tk.Button(self.regions_frame, text="Plot Regions", width=13, border=0, command = self.plot_data)
        self.regions_data.place(x=120, y = 450)
        
    
        self.listregions = tk.Listbox(self.list_regions_frame,listvariable= self.variable_regions, selectmode=tk.MULTIPLE, height=17)
        self.listregions.place(x = 10, y = 15)
        
    
        
    def load_data(self,event):
        
        if self.numdata >2:
            self.limit_data()
        else: 
            # Show file dialog to choose file
            filepath = filedialog.askopenfilename()
            var_list = sio.whosmat(filepath,appendmat=False)
            last_var_name = var_list[0][0]
            mat_data = np.transpose(sio.loadmat(filepath)[last_var_name])
            
            if self.numdata == 0:
                self.condition = mat_data
                self.data_name_label.config(text=last_var_name)
                self.update_num_data()
            
            elif self.numdata == 1:
                self.condition1 = mat_data
                self.data_name_label1.config(text=last_var_name)
                self.update_num_data()
                
            elif self.numdata == 2:
                self.condition2 = mat_data
                self.data_name_label2.config(text=last_var_name)
                self.update_num_data()
    
    def load_regions(self):
        regionspath = filedialog.askopenfilename()
        self.regions = np.loadtxt(regionspath, dtype = str)
        reg = []
        for i in range(len(self.regions)):
            reg.append(self.regions[i])
        self.variable_regions = tk.Variable(value = reg)
        self.listregions.config(listvariable= self.variable_regions)
    
    def update_num_data(self):
        self.numdata = self.numdata + 1
        print(self.numdata)
   
    def limit_data(self):
        result = tk.messagebox.askyesno("Confirmation", "The max amount of data has been reached. Do you want to restart the selection?")
        if result:
            self.numdata = 0
            self.data_name_label.config(text='No data')
            self.data_name_label1.config(text='No data')
            self.data_name_label2.config(text='No data')
            self.condition = []
            self.condition1 = []
            self.condition2 = []
            
    def change_data_name(self, event):
        name = tk.simpledialog.askstring(title = 'New Name', prompt = 'Enter New Data Name')
        self.data_name_label.config(text=name)
    
    def plot_data(self):
        self.data_plot = None
        if self.data_plot:
            self.data_plot.destroy()
        fig = Figure(figsize = (5,5), dpi = 100)
        self.selected_regions_indx = self.listregions.curselection()
        self.selected_regions = [self.listregions.get(i) for i in self.selected_regions_indx]
        plot1 = fig.add_subplot(111)
        y = np.transpose(self.condition[:,self.selected_regions_indx])
        y = np.squeeze(y)
        print(np.shape(y))
        plot1.plot(y)
        canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig,master = self.plot_frame)  
        self.data_plot = canvas.get_tk_widget().pack()
```